# Convert decimal to date format in r

Tags: r, datetime

I have the data frame which has column of Date&time in the decimal format Date time is current format and expected format are like this

```
   Date Time      Expected format
1  43824.838  2019-12-27 20:06:43
2  43824.842  2019-12-27 20:12:28
3  43824.846  2019-12-27 20:18:14
4  43824.850  2019-12-27 20:24:00
5  43824.854  2019-12-27 20:29:45
6  43824.858  2019-12-27 20:35:31
7  43824.863  2019-12-27 20:42:43
8  43824.867  2019-12-27 20:48:28
```

With the following decimal date times:

```
c(43824.838, 43824.842, 43824.846, 43824.85, 43824.854, 43824.858, 43824.863, 43824.867)
```

Answer (score 5):

In base R you can do

```
as_datetime <- function(x) as.POSIXct("1900-01-01") + as.difftime(x, units = "days")

dates <- c(43824.838, 43824.842, 43824.846, 43824.85, 
           43824.854, 43824.858, 43824.863, 43824.867)

as_datetime(dates)
#> [1] "2019-12-27 20:06:43 GMT" "2019-12-27 20:12:28 GMT" "2019-12-27 20:18:14 GMT"
#> [4] "2019-12-27 20:24:00 GMT" "2019-12-27 20:29:45 GMT" "2019-12-27 20:35:31 GMT"
#> [7] "2019-12-27 20:42:43 GMT" "2019-12-27 20:48:28 GMT"
```